# Android Studio build finished, but cannot run at real device

Tags: android

This is the main activity of xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/background"
    tools:context="com.example.liew.idelivery.MainActivity">


<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="250dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:src="@drawable/logo" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtSlogan"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/slogan"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic" />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignUp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sign Up"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp" />

    <info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        android:id="@+id/btnSignIn"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_margin="8dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="Sign In"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        app:buttonColor="@color/btnSignUp"
        app:cornerRadius="4dp"
        app:shadowColor="@android:color/black"
        app:shadowEnabled="true"
        app:shadowHeight="5dp" />


</LinearLayout>
```

And this is the error that i found in my logcat.

```
  E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.liew.idelivery, PID: 18266
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
```

ComponentInfo{com.example.liew.idelivery/com.example.liew.idelivery.MainActivit 
  y}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating 
      class info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
        at 
     android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2462)
        at 
     android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2534)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:164)

Answer (score 0):

I think the error occurred as there is no **closing tag** for `RelativeLayout`. If the problem still persists try to attach the `MainActivity` file as well, I'll check it.

One last suggestion: Try to use `ConstraintLayout` instead of `LinearLayout` and `RelativeLayout` :)

Answer (score 0):

android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #43: Error inflating class

Exception arise only there are something wrong in xml file first of all your xml files need to close with the tag

```
</RelativeLayout>
```

Other possibility is that custom views which are you using,  make sure the views are on the correct path (package name exist with the path)

```
info.hoang8f.widget.FButton
```